# iframe injection attack

Tags: apache, iframe, code-injection

My website (hosted on a Windows/Apache(XAMPP) server) seems to suffer from an iframe injection attack. The iframes appear at the top of pages and disappear at times for no obvious reason. There are also several other symptoms:

- The html code for the iframe does not actually appear in any of the html/php files (no base64 code either)
- The iframe appears in the directory listings generated by apache. (i.e. there are no html/php files to investigate)
- The problem seems to disappear when the website is accessed through HTTPS.
- Nothing noticeable in htaccess files.
- FTP password has been changed and FTP access monitored, doesn't seem to be the issue.

Any idea on what is causing it or how to stop it?

Comment: Redeploy the website from source control?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be a man-in-the-middle attack.

Unlikely, I know, but possible.

If you are accessing from public WiFi or have a mysterious van outside your building, this could be it.

Basically, a man-in-the-middle attack injects code into webpages after they come back from the server and before they reach the client.

However, MITM attacks usually only work on HTTP (unless they're using SSLStrip, sorry, got off topic for a moment). This could explain the problems going away on HTTPS.